# product price in cart turns 0 on cart update

Tags: cart

I've created a plugin on afterGetPrice() to live update the price of product of Simple products. Everything works fine until I update product quantity or add more product in the cart. Whenever I add more product to cart price of previously added products turns 0. Even if I change the quantity in cart product price turns 0. Here is my plugin code:

```
public function afterGetPrice(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product, $price){
                $premium = 0;
                $weight = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('fine_weight')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
                $attr_premium = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('premium');
                if($attr_premium)
                        $premium = $attr_premium->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
                $livePrice = $this->_livePrices->getLivePrices($metal);
                return $livePrice*$weight+(round($premium*$livePrice/100,2));
        }
```

Comment: Share the code which you have done.

Comment: Thanks @DhirenVasoya. I've updated my question with code